# How to Change the default keyboard "Send" or default button globally for any application in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, customization

I'm working on a Flutter application, and I'm trying to customize the behavior of the keyboard's "`Send`" or default button globally, irrespective of the current input field or screen. I want to change the default action that occurs when the user presses the "`Send`" button on the keyboard.

Is there a way to achieve this in Flutter? I've explored the `TextField` and `TextFormField` widgets, but it seems like the behavior is tied to each input field. I want to override or customize the default action for the "`Send`" button throughout the entire application.

Any guidance or example code on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to handle the "Send" button press globally, without having to handle it separately for each input field.

Answer (score 1):

If you see from the source code of `TextField`, the `textInputAction` property that is passed to the `EditableText` constructor inside the `build` method is solely taken from the widget parameter.

[lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L1464](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L1464)

```dart
textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
```

It means that there is no way to control that behavior by setting some kind of option globally. The only way to achieve this is by creating a new custom widget that extends `TextField`, but of course, you would still have to change every `TextField` widget to that custom widget manually.

Comment: I know this I want enable for globally

Comment: As shown in my answer, what you're trying to achieve is impossible